# an application required libstdc++ for GLIBCXX_3_4_9 library on RHEL 5 64bit system

Tags: rpm

I need to have libstdc++ which contains GLIBCXX_3_4_9 library for 64 bit platform on redhat 5 system. This is required by an application. I tried to install following rpms from RHEL 6 repository but recevied several dependency failure error messages

```
 libstdc++-docs-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
 libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
 libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
 compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.x86_64.rpm
 compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6.i686.rpm


 # rpm -Uvh libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6.i686.rpm compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.x86_64.rpm

            warning: libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID fd431d51
        error: Failed dependencies:
                glibc >= 2.10.90-7 is needed by libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
                rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
                rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
                rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
                rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
                libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.12) is needed by compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6.i686
                rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6.i686
                rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6.i686
                rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.x86_64
                rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.x86_64
                libstdc++ = 4.1.2-54.el5 is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-54.el5.x86_64
                libstdc++ = 4.1.2 is needed by (installed) libstdc++44-devel-4.4.7-1.el5.x86_64
                libstdc++ = 4.1.2 is needed by (installed) libstdc++44-devel-4.4.7-1.el5.i386
                libstdc++-devel = 4.1.2-54.el5 is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-54.el5.x86_64
```

Is there a way to get this libstdc++.so.6.0.9 or higher install on redheat 5 (64bit) system?

Update:

Here is the output of `yum search`

```
   # yum search gcc-c++ 
   Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
   This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use                subscription-manager to register.
   This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
  ======================================================================================         Matched: gcc-c++ ======================================================================================
    gcc-c++.x86_64 : C++ support for GCC
```

I have downloaded the latest version from gcc++ from rhn 6 repository but received the following error:

```
        # yum install gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
        Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
        This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
        This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
        Setting up Install Process
        Examining gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm: gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
        Marking gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm as an update to gcc-c++-4.1.2-54.el5.x86_64
        Resolving Dependencies
        --> Running transaction check
        ---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-4.el6 set to be updated
        --> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.7-4.el6 for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.4.7-4.el6 for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.4.7-4.el6 for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: gcc-c++
        --> Running transaction check
        ---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-4.el6 set to be updated
        --> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.7-4.el6 for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.4.7-4.el6 for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.4.7-4.el6 for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) for package: gcc-c++
        --> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: gcc-c++
        ---> Package gmp.x86_64 0:4.1.4-10.el5 set to be updated
        --> Finished Dependency Resolution
        gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 from /gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 has depsolving problems
          --> Missing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.4.7-4.el6 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 from /gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 has depsolving problems
          --> Missing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 from /gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 has depsolving problems
          --> Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 from /gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 has depsolving problems
          --> Missing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.7-4.el6 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 from /gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 has depsolving problems
          --> Missing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.4.7-4.el6 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 from /gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 has depsolving problems
          --> Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        Error: Missing Dependency: libstdc++ = 4.4.7-4.el6 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        Error: Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        Error: Missing Dependency: gcc = 4.4.7-4.el6 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        Error: Missing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.4.7-4.el6 is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        Error: Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
        Error: Missing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (/gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script did it all. It not only download and compile GCC4.4 package but also download and compile necessary dependencies. You may need to install `#yum install zsh` before run this script since this script is running under zsh shell. Thanks to Simon Heimlicher for making this script available on his [blog](http://simon.heimlicher.com/articles/2012/10/19/compile-gcc-4-dot-4-on-rhel-5).

```
    #!/usr/bin/env zsh
    # Download and compile GCC 4.4

    set -ue

    # Set minimal PATH to make sure we compile with the system compiler
    export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    # Use bash as the shell for everything GNU
    export CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/bash

    # Set to true for verbose output
    VERBOSE=${VERBOSE:=false}

    out () { printf "\n%b\n\n" "$@" >&2 }
    fail () { printf "\n%b\n\n" " $@ " >&2; exit 1 }

    DSTROOT=${DSTROOT:=$HOME/local}
    PKGROOT=${PKGROOT:=$DSTROOT/pkg}
    SCRATCH=${SCRATCH:-$HOME/scratch}
    SRCDIR=${SRCDIR:=$SCRATCH/gcc/src}
    BUILDDIR=${BUILDDIR:=$SCRATCH/gcc/build}

    GCC_URL=http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.4.7/gcc-4.4.7.tar.bz2

    GCC_PREREQUISITE_URLS=(
    ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
    ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2
    ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz
    http://www.mr511.de/software/libelf-0.8.13.tar.gz
    )

    out "DSTROOT='$DSTROOT'
    PKGROOT='$PKGROOT'
    SRCDIR='$SRCDIR'
    BUILDDIR='$BUILDDIR'"

    runcmd() {
     RUN_RET=0
     RUN_CWD='.'
     RUN_FORCE=false
     o_cwd=''; o_force=''
     zparseopts -D -K -- c:=o_cwd f=o_force -cwd:=o_cwd -force=o_force
     if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
         print "Usage: runcmd [-f] <command line to run>" >&2
         return 1
     fi
     if [[ -n $o_cwd ]]; then RUN_CWD=$o_cwd[2]; fi
     if [[ -n $o_force ]]; then RUN_FORCE=true; fi
     cmdline=$@
     if $VERBOSE; then
         print "Running\n    ${(@)cmdline}\nRUN_FORCE=$RUN_FORCE RUN_CWD=$RUN_CWD" >&2
     fi
     ( set +ue; cd $RUN_CWD && print ${(@)cmdline} | $CONFIG_SHELL -sue; )
     RUN_RET=$?
     if [[ $RUN_RET -ne 0 ]]; then
         if $RUN_FORCE; then
             print "\n### $cmdline\nexit $RUN_RET in CWD=$RUN_CWD\n" >&2
         else
             print "\n\n### $cmdline\nexit $RUN_RET in CWD=$RUN_CWD\nAbort." >&2
             exit $RUN_RET
         fi
     fi
     return $RUN_RET
    }

    prepare_pkg () {
     local srcdir=$1
     local url=$2
     local pkgvers=${${url##*/}%.(tar*|zip)}
     local pkg=${pkgvers%-*}
     local vers=${pkgvers#*-}
     local suffix=${${url##*/}##*.}
     out "Fetching $pkgvers from $url"
     case $suffix in
         gz)
         runcmd -c $srcdir curl -L $url \| tar xz
         ;;
         bz2|tbz)
         runcmd -c $srcdir curl -L $url \| tar xj
         ;;
         zip)
         runcmd -c $srcdir curl -L $url \| funzip
         ;;
         *)
         fail "Unknown archive format: $url"
         ;;
     esac
     if [[ ! -d $srcdir/$pkgvers ]]; then
         fail "Extraction of download from $url failed"
     fi
     runcmd -c $srcdir ln -sf $pkgvers $pkg
    }

    if $VERBOSE; then
     printf "Using system compiler: '%s'" $(which gcc)
     gcc --version
    fi

    out "Making directories \n$DSTROOT\n$PKGROOT\n$SRCDIR\n$BUILDDIR"

    runcmd mkdir -p $DSTROOT $PKGROOT $SRCDIR $BUILDDIR

    GCC_PKG=${${GCC_URL##*/}%.(tar*|zip)}
    GCC_SRC=$SRCDIR/$GCC_PKG
    GCC_PREFIX=$PKGROOT/$GCC_PKG
    GCC_BUILD=$BUILDDIR/$GCC_PKG-build

    if [[ -d $GCC_SRC ]]; then
     out "Using GCC downloaded at $GCC_SRC"
    else
     out "Downloading GCC"
     prepare_pkg $SRCDIR $GCC_URL
    fi

    out "Downloading prerequisites"
    for pkg ($GCC_PREREQUISITE_URLS); do
     prepare_pkg $GCC_SRC $pkg
    done

    if [[ -d $GCC_BUILD ]]; then
     out "Running 'make distclean' in $GCC_BUILD"
     runcmd -c $GCC_BUILD -f make distclean
    else
     out "Making GCC build directory $GCC_BUILD"
     runcmd mkdir -p $GCC_BUILD
    fi

    out "Configuring GCC"
    runcmd -c $GCC_BUILD $GCC_SRC/configure --prefix=$GCC_PREFIX \
    --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran \
    --enable-threads=posix \
    --enable-tls \
    --enable-libgomp \
    --enable-lto \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-nls \
    --disable-multilib \
    --with-fpmath=sse

    out "Compiling GCC"
    runcmd -c $GCC_BUILD make -j 8 all

    out "Installing GCC"
    runcmd -c $GCC_BUILD make -j 8 install

    if which stow &>/dev/null; then
     out "Using 'stow' to symlink GCC from $GCC_PKG"
     runcmd -c $PKGROOT stow $GCC_PKG
    else
     out "Package manager 'stow' not found. GCC is installed in $GCC_PREFIX"
    fi

    print "All done"
```

Answer (score 0):

RHEL6

```
root@ibxsv-asnis1 ~]# rpm -q --provides libstdc++
libstdc++ = 4.4.4-15.el6
libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.1)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.2)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.3)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.1)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.10)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.12)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.13)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.2)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.3)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.4)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.5)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.6)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.7)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.8)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit)
libstdc++ = 4.4.7-4.el6
libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.4.7-4.el6
[root@ibxsv-asnis1 ~]# rpm -q libstdc++
libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score -1):

When you install g++ with yum, itself solves dependecies problems.

So try:

```
yum search g++
```

then find out pacjage of `g++`,  When you wan to  install it, itslef install its depenecies.One of its depency is `libstdc++`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my question for update. I need to install latest version of g++ on rhn 5. no luck so far