# Installing software on RedHat with libstdc++ dependency errors

Tags: rhel, gcc, libraries

I realize this has been asked multiple times, but after reading through the responses, I still cannot get it.

I'm trying to install software called [Ovito](https://ovito.org/index.php/download) on RedHat Enterprise 7 and am getting the following errors:

```
[adam@pc bin]$ sudo ./ovito
[sudo] password for adam: 
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libGui.so)
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libCore.so)
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libCore.so)
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libQt5Concurrent.so.5)
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libQt5Gui.so.5)
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libQt5Network.so.5)
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libQt5Core.so.5)
./ovito: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/adam/Downloads/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin/../lib/ovito/libQt5Core.so.5)
```

---

I installed the newest libstdc++ package, as suggested in the first answer of this post:

[libX11.so.6 Not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/libx11-so-6-not-found)

Result:

```
[root@pc bin]# yum -y install libstdc++
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

---

I tried fixing the simlinks(?), as suggested in most of the StackExchange answers on here. I followed the commands from gnu.org:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

and the commands on the first answer in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/how-to-fix-program-name-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxx

In the end, I've tried the following:

1

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

2

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${prefix}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

...

and other combinations. What confuses me is that there's a `/usr/local/lib64` path and what appears to be a `computer/lib64` path.

---

This post provided scripts for RedHat Enterprise versions 5&6 for someone with a similar issue, but not RedHat/RHEL 7:

[an application required libstdc++ for GLIBCXX_3_4_9 library on RHEL 5 64bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156509/an-application-required-libstdc-for-glibcxx-3-4-9-library-on-rhel-5-64bit-syst)

(not that I yet know how to run the scripts anyway)

Answer (score -1):

I e-mailed the software developer of this particular program (Ovito) who gave me the following instructions:

> Download and extract the previous version of OVITO, version 2.8.2:
>
> http://ovito.org/download/
>
> in the lib/ovito/ directory you will find two files named stdlibc++.* 
>   Copy both to the same place in the newer OVITO package (v2.9.0). Then
>   try to run it.
>
> This stdlibc++ library is exactly the version OVITO needs. But it is
>   no longer included with the binary package, because on some systems it
>   leads to a conflict with the OpenGL graphics driver, which needs the
>   system’s libstdc++ version.

Ovito 2.9.0 installed correctly after following these instructions.